# SwiftUI ShareLink: Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

I am getting following warning in the console when presenting SwiftUI's ShareLink:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x12f7a82d0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (16 241; 343 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002409c80>>
```

I am curious if this is my wrong configuration / presentation of SwiftUI's ShareLink in SwiftUI app or this is a problem within SwiftUI wrapper around UIActivityViewController

```
.toolbar(content: {
    ShareLink(item: Image(uiImage: fileImage),preview: SharePreview(displayName, image: Image(uiImage: fileImage)))
})
```

Question relates to iOS 16.2